# Handling Session in async methods

Tags: c#, .net, session, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to MVC5 and trying to implement sessions with in async methods in Controllers. I have created method like this

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var userId = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Session["UserId"]);

    var userDetail = await service.GetBy(currentUserId),
}
```

This session thing, always fails with the following message

> Server Error in Application. Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int64]' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

(Sorry, I am not able to post screenshot of actual error, as do not have enough reputation points on this site)

I also tried to do it like this

```
var userId = await Task<long>.FromResult(Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Session["UserId"]));
```

and

```
var userId = await (Session["UserId"] as Task<long>);
```

and

```
var userId = await Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Session["UserId"]);
```

But, it always gives the same message. Can somebody please point me to the correct approach. Also, if we can not use session with in async methods, then what would be the best solution for it.

Comment: You've changed the code from `Task<int>` to `Task<long>`. Which one actually failed for you?

Comment: It should be Task<long> only. My value is of type Int64. Task<int> was incorrect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error implies that `HttpContext.Session["UserId"]` is storing a `Task` instead of an actual `int64`. That means the somewhere in your code, where you store the userId in the session you are probably forgetting to await a task for its result.

Probably looks like:

```
HttpContext.Session["UserId"] = GetUserIdAsync();
```

Instead of:

```
HttpContext.Session["UserId"] = await GetUserIdAsync();
```

---

You could also await the stored task as you've tried to do (with the wrong type conversion):

```
var userId = await ((Task<Int64>)HttpContext.Session["UserId"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked for me. I was missing await keyword when storing the userid in session. Like this HttpContext.Session["UserId"] = await GetUserIdAsync(); I probably visited this line many a times but never able to find out the reason. Thank you once again